# Python - pyqt xcb plugin with thread error

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using Ubuntu, when I run my program from pyqt, I got this error,

```
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0xa549e0) is not the object's thread (0x4b7bfc0).
Cannot move to target thread (0xa549e0)

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/mialo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

`pip3 list|grep Qt` for this command, I got

```
PyQt5                        5.15.5              
PyQt5-Qt5                    5.15.2              
PyQt5-sip                    12.9.0              
QtPy                         1.11.1
```

I tried many solutions from uninstalling opencv-python and installig opencv-headless, `export DISPLAY=:1.0` etc

But nothing worked, what should we do to solve this issue,

thanks

Comment: Does it happen with *any* PyQt program? Try with a basic QApplication and show a QWidget.

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same problem when I deleted the qt folder the error was solved

in this path delete qt folder

```
/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/qt/
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you use opencv in your python code?

try:
`pip uninstall opencv-python`
, and remove your cv2 in the code

If this works, downgrading your opencv-python, maybe `opencv-python==4.3.0.36`.

see here for more information:
https://github.com/Yuliang-Liu/Curve-Text-Detector/issues/11